# How to write a function to double numbers and pass them as to an object

Tags: javascript

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

function doubling(number) {
    number *= 2;
    return number;
}

obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    doubled = doubling(numbers[i]);
    obj[numbers[i]] = doubled;
    console.log(obj);
```

When I run my code, it prints '10' when what I want is for it to print {1:2, 2:4, 3:6, 4:8, 5:10}. Why does this happen?

Comment: You for loop is missing {}

Comment: as Bas says: http://jsfiddle.net/LW6z7/ works correctly

Comment: Without the curly braces, the for loop is only looping the line directly after it.  See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Control_structures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function doubling(number) {
    number *= 2;
    return number;
}

obj = {};

// your problem was here you were missing the curly braces
// so it was only executing the first line in the loop
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    doubled = doubling(numbers[i]);
    obj[numbers[i]] = doubled;
}
console.log(obj);
```

Your original loop was basically this...

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    doubled = doubling(numbers[i]);
}
obj[numbers[i]] = doubled;  // numbers[i] is undefined so it 
                            // sets obj[undefined] = 10 
                            // (the value of double after the loop)
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Maybe a word of explanation... ?

Comment: Added explanation - as a general rule of thumb I never use the no curly braces shorthand because this has bitten me in the past as well.

Comment: @bard Yes it is. I **always** put the curly braces down, even if I am "100% sure" that I won't be changing the statement. It just saves time later when 100% becomes 30% becomes 0% and you're making the change you thought you wouldn't. Plus, it makes it crystal clear what is happening in your code, which Johnny Nextguy will thank you for (if there IS a Johnny Nextguy)